# How can I tell if my Ubuntu kernel leap second bug free?

Tags: kernel

I have few Ubuntu boxes

```
Linux SERV01 2.6.32-38-server #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 4 11:26:59 UTC 2012 x86_64   GNU/Linux
```

How can I check if the installed kernel is leap second bug free ?

Don't have much experience with Ubuntu, RHEL provided a detector but did not find anything similar for Ubuntu.

Comment: Dammit copy paste error: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1020285, I missed out the 5 at the end.

Comment: reposted from a comment by laughing_man: *From the link above, I found the following comment by Herton R. Krzesinski (herton): "Fixed already on Oneiric (3.0.0-24.40) and Precise (3.2.0-29.46), they didn't have a BugLink pointing here as the fixes were applied through stable updates, so no automatic status change to Fix Released." This means that the kernel version for Ubuntu 11.10 with the fix is 3.0.0-24.40, and the kernel version for Ubuntu 12.04 with the fix is 3.2.0-29.46.*

Answer (score 1):

From the link above, I found the following comment by Herton R. Krzesinski (herton):

> Fixed already on Oneiric (3.0.0-24.40) and Precise (3.2.0-29.46), they didn't have a BugLink pointing here as the fixes were applied through stable updates, so no automatic status change to Fix Released.

This means that the kernel version for Ubuntu 11.10 with the fix is 3.0.0-24.40, and the kernel version for Ubuntu 12.04 with the fix is 3.2.0-29.46.