# Will Leap Second 2015 affect our servers?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, kernel, ntp

We are using Ubuntu 12.04 and ubuntu 14.04 servers. These servers using default time settings and we have not installed ntp in these servers.

**Ubuntu 14.04**

```
root@ubuntu14:~# uname -a
Linux ubuntu14 3.13.0-52-generic #85-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 29 16:44:17 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@ubuntu14:~# cat /etc/default/ntpdate | grep  NTPSERVERS
NTPSERVERS="ntp.ubuntu.com"
```

**Ubuntu 12.04**

```
root@ubuntu12:~# uname -a
Linux ubuntu12 3.2.0-23-virtual #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 22:29:03 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@home:~# cat /etc/default/ntpdate | grep  NTPSERVERS
NTPSERVERS="ntp.ubuntu.com"
```

I can see these discussion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608618/how-can-i-tell-if-my-ubuntu-kernel-leap-second-bug-free) and also on this [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1020285) . For Ubuntu 12.4 (Precise) it shows "Fix Released" but no information for Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty).

So can you please check the kernel version of our servers and let us know in these servers we need to do any changes so that Leap Second June 2015 will not impact anything wrong in our servers.

Can anyone please help us on it.

Answer (score 6):

No information is given for Ubuntu 14.04 because the kernel in 14.04 was released well after that bug was fixed. 3.13, therefore, already contains a fix for the bug. As for 12.04, the fix was released with `3.2.0-29.46` where you have `3.2.0-23` - so I'm inclined to think your kernel is still affected. Upgrade, people! `linux-image-virtual` for 12.04 is currently at `3.2.0-86`.